# How to add white space in Bootstrap until certain element is on top of screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this image on my website that in Bootstrap 4 and want to have the image be on top of my user's screen when certain button or image is clicked by adding white space to the bottom of the website therefore the image is at the top screen when my website is scrolled all the way down (which I have figured out with JS function). How can keep adding whitespace to website until the image is on top of the screen? I have come up with a solution of having a certain element in CSS with the margins fixed measurements and have it visible when clicked but want it be for various sizes of viewports.

```js
scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);

function scrollSmoothToBottom (id) {
  $(scrollingElement).animate({
     scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight
  }, 500);
}
window.onload = function(){
// Make WhiteSpace not on website
document.getElementById("whiteSpace").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click",function(){
// Once Button is clicked make whitespace visible then scroll to bottom
document.getElementById("whiteSpace").style.display = "block";
scrollSmoothToBottom ();
});

}
```

```css
.space{
 margin:520px; 
}
```

```html
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <center>
        <h1 id  = "collegeNameTitle">Name</h1>
        <h3>Student Size</h3>
         <span class="badge badge-success even-larger-badge" id = "collegeStudentSizeText">10</span>
         <h3>Acceptance Rate:</h3>
          <span class="badge badge-success even-larger-badge" id = "collegeAcceptanceRateText">10</span>
          <h3>Student-Faculty Ratio:</h3><span class="badge badge-success even-larger-badge" id = "collegeRatioText">10</span>
        </center>
<center><button id = "submitButton"><img class = "collegeImage"src="sample.png" id  = "collegeImage"></button></center>
<div id = "whiteSpace" class ="space" visibility = "hidden">
  </div>
```

Example of how I want my website to be. This is my code right now and want it so in CSS I have no fixed measurement of space but until the image reaches to the top.

Comment: Is it possible to post a sample code reproducing the issue?

Comment: @DavidSalomen , I have inserted my code and an example of how I want it implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the position of your `img` to be at the top of your screen when  you click on a `button` then you can try the code below:

```js
const theImg = document.getElementById("myImg");
const theBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
theBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  theImg.style.position="fixed";
  theImg.style.top=0;
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-item: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
img{
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Button</button>
<img id="myImg" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg">
```

If you're not familiar with positions in css then, it'd be best for you to check [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).